# Rails ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone please tell me how can I fix that error : ?

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#create

Couldn't find Movie without an ID

```
def create
    @movie = Movie.find params[:movie_id]   #new post
    @post = @movie.posts.create params[:post]
    @post.user_id = @current_user.id
    @post.save          
    respond_to do |format|              
        format.html {redirect_to @movie}
    end
```

end

I am trying to add posts to my movies. I have the text field there but once I press post this comes up. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post your PostsController#create action code

Comment: I edited my first post and added the create method there.

Comment: Can you include your `new` action code and the code from your `new` view?

Comment: Oh you are trying to add a nested comment to the movie in the form. Do you have form_for [@movie, @post]

Answer (score 0):

It means that the value of the parameter `params[:movie_id]` is empty. Make sure you are passing a value for it.

Comment: it doesn't necessarily mean that the params[:movie_id] is empty but it means that the record was not found...

Comment: Leo, it's not correct. If the record was not found the exception would be the same but the message different. In this case, is exactly because the parameter evaluates to a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a @movie object in your view with the form. To pass the id to the controller you can add in your ...htm.erb file:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("movie_id", @movie.id) %>
```

this will populate your `params[:movie_id]` variable with the id

If this doesn't help, post more code

Comment: Still not having any luck with it but thank you both for your help

Comment: please post more code. I would like to see your ´.html.erb` file and your Movie and Post model.